# Combining lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, combinations

I am trying to combine 2 lists and want to form combinations.

```
a = ['ibm','dell']
b = ['strength','weekness']
```

I want to form combinations like `['ibm strength','ibm weekness','dell strength','dell weakness']`.

I tried to use zip or concatenated the lists. I also used itertools but it doesn't give me desired output. Please help.

```
a = ['ibm','dell']
b = ['strength','weekness']
c = a + b
itertools.combinations(c,2)
for a in a:
    for b in b:
        print a +b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Try this:

```
import itertools

a = ['ibm', 'dell']
b = ['strength', 'weakness']

[' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(a, b)]
=> ['ibm strength', 'ibm weakness', 'dell strength', 'dell weakness']
```

To loop over the results don't forget that `itertools.product()` returns an *iterator* that can be consumed only once. If you need it at a later time, convert it into a list (as I did above, using a list comprehension) and store the result in a variable, for future use. For example:

```
lst = list(itertools.product(a, b))
for a, b in lst:
    print a, b
```

Comment: Thanks oscar for the prompt response. also can you please explain why the list items start dissapearing when i loop over the items and join them. as in after i use loop the list gets empty

Comment: Is amazing this way Óscar! ;) Nice one!

Comment: @RaghavShaligram That doesn't happen to me … please post the code that's causing the problem. Also, you should save the list in a variable, for future usage

Comment: @ÓscarLópez i just updated the code and used a nested loop. The list items starts vanishing..

Comment: @RaghavShaligram You are not using the code in my answer … anyway, see my update. Remember that the functions in `itertools` return _iterators_ (not lists), that can be traversed only once. If you need to use them at a later point convert them to lists. And you _must_ save the result in a variable, simply calling the function won't do anything

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I am going to use the code that you gave me, but was curious to know why that happens. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), you want [*itertools.product()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of combinations.

A nested for-loop would also work:

```
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        c = a + b
        print(c)
```